# Low Search filter by get parameters

Tags: low-search, get, filtering

I have a strange problem for a new template. I'm trying to retrieve some data from database based on query params.

My query looks like:

```
{exp:low_search:results channel="channel_name" status="active" disable="categories|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" dynamic="no"
  {if '{get:trip_group}' != ''} 
    child:trips_race_trip_group='{get:trip_group}'
  {if:elseif '{get:trip_type}' != ''} 
    child:trips_trip_type='{get:trip_type}'
  {/if}
}
```

My problem is that every times the both conditions are added to query and I get an error result for each iteration result. For example if *{get:trip_group}* is empty

> child:trips_race_trip_group='' } child:trips_race_trip_group='' }
>   child:trips_race_trip_group='' child:trips_trip_type='tbt-camps' }

But it works perfectly if I do it without if conditions, the results are correct; something like:

```
{exp:low_search:results channel="channel_name" status="active" disable="categories|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" dynamic="no" 
  child:trips_race_trip_group='{get:trip_group}'
}
```

or

```
{exp:low_search:results channel="channel_name" status="active" disable="categories|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" dynamic="no"
  child:trips_trip_type='{get:trip_type}'
}
```

Do you have any ideas what is happening here ?

Comment: The only solution founded is this: {if "{get:trip_group}" != ""}
     {exp:low_search:results channel="channel_name" status="active" disable="categories|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" dynamic="no" 
        child:trips_race_trip_group="{get:trip_group}"
    } 
{if:elseif '{get:trip_type}' != ''}
     {exp:low_search:results channel="channel_name" status="active"
        disable="categories|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" dynamic="no" 
        child:trips_trip_type='{get:trip_type}' 
    } 
{if:else}
     {exp:low_search:results channel="channel_name" status="active"}  
{/if}

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Low Search form and GET vars, then you don't need to add those parameters to the Results tag -- they'll get picked up and are applied automatically, as long as the name is correct in your input elements, ie:

```
<select name="child:trips_trip_type">
```

and not

```
<select name="trip_type">
```